# Error on sign in page after adding devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, rubygems

I am working on my local on an app that used to work perfectly. But now, I get this message error when connecting to my `localhost`. I use the [`devise-2.2.3` gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-12 16:54:42 +0200
Creating scope :closed. Overwriting existing method MergeRequest.closed.
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/devise (1.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.haml (26.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 59ms
```

The I noticed there were no `layouts/_head.html.haml`. So does somebody has an idea of the origin of such an error ?

As suggested, I post the full stack though I don't think it is much informative than what I posted before ;)

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-12 17:16:27 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/devise (1.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.haml (88.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 94ms

ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: unexpected IDENTIFIER
  (in /Users/git/gitlab/app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee)):
    5:     GitLab
    6:   = favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico'
    7:   = stylesheet_link_tag    "application"
    8:   = javascript_include_tag "application", "internationalization.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"
    9:   = csrf_meta_tags
    10:   = include_gon
    11: 
  app/views/layouts/_head.html.haml:8:in `_app_views_layouts__head_html_haml__3074448813358061809_70101269487200'
  app/views/layouts/devise.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_layouts_devise_html_haml__1317746148502442303_70101202019240'


Started GET "/static.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-12 17:16:28 +0200
Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"static.css"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-12 17:16:28 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/devise (1.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.haml (25.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 32ms

ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: unexpected IDENTIFIER
  (in /Users/git/gitlab/app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee)):
    5:     GitLab
    6:   = favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico'
    7:   = stylesheet_link_tag    "application"
    8:   = javascript_include_tag "application", "internationalization.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"
    9:   = csrf_meta_tags
    10:   = include_gon
    11: 
  app/views/layouts/_head.html.haml:8:in `_app_views_layouts__head_html_haml__3074448813358061809_70101269487200'
  app/views/layouts/devise.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_layouts_devise_html_haml__1317746148502442303_70101202019240'


Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-12 17:16:28 +0200
Processing by ProjectsController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"favicon.ico"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-12 17:16:28 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as */*
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/devise (1.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.haml (27.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 33ms

ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: unexpected IDENTIFIER
  (in /Users/git/gitlab/app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee)):
    5:     GitLab
    6:   = favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico'
    7:   = stylesheet_link_tag    "application"
    8:   = javascript_include_tag "application", "internationalization.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"
    9:   = csrf_meta_tags
    10:   = include_gon
    11: 
  app/views/layouts/_head.html.haml:8:in `_app_views_layouts__head_html_haml__3074448813358061809_70101269487200'
  app/views/layouts/devise.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_layouts_devise_html_haml__1317746148502442303_70101202019240'


Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-12 17:16:28 +0200
Processing by ProjectsController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"favicon.ico"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-12 17:16:28 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as */*
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/devise (1.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.haml (25.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31ms

ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: unexpected IDENTIFIER
  (in /Users/git/gitlab/app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee)):
    5:     GitLab
    6:   = favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico'
    7:   = stylesheet_link_tag    "application"
    8:   = javascript_include_tag "application", "internationalization.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"
    9:   = csrf_meta_tags
    10:   = include_gon
    11: 
  app/views/layouts/_head.html.haml:8:in `_app_views_layouts__head_html_haml__3074448813358061809_70101269487200'
  app/views/layouts/devise.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_layouts_devise_html_haml__1317746148502442303_70101202019240'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the layout is not your issue (I don't think), when posting an error on stack overflow, it's super important that you post the **stack trace.**

The stack trace is the holy grail that holds all of the knowledge about the error, and without it, we are totally lost. Post the stack trace, and try restarting your rails server. Make sure you migrate your database, and then maybe we can fix the error.

This line:

```
= javascript_include_tag "application", "internationalization.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"
```

is broken.

I'm not sure why, probably because you've listed out the JS filess on the same line. There may be a problem with the javascript file itself, not sure, but that is where the error is.

Comment: Ok now I get it, I had some ownership problem with this file `_head.html.haml` so it wasn't seen neither by my usual user nor by `sudo`

Comment: Oh I see, the error was in the head of the document, which you have extracted to a partial. `chown` is the command you need